# AJAX ready event once HTML page and scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, document-ready, html5-history

I'm creating a web application that has multiple pages of content that I'm loading dynamically with AJAX and the HTML5 History API. When a user attempts to change the page, the new content is loaded with a $.get and injected into the body, like so:

```
$.get("somepage.html", function (data)
{
    $("body").html(data);
});
```

Most of these pages require additional scripts to be loaded. This wouldn't be an issue except for the fact that $(document).ready fires before these scripts are loaded. Somepage.html looks something like this.

```
<script src='http://getjquerysomewhere/'></script>
<script src='my_script_that_depends_on_jQuery'></script>
```

This issue is complicated by the fact that these pages must have the ability to be loaded on their own. I'm therefore unsure how I can eliminate the $(document).ready functions without affecting this behavior as well.

How should I approach this problem?

Comment: You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: That looks awesome. It's a shame it doesn't have widespread support yet.

Comment: There are several libraries that implement the Promise interface.

Comment: Seems to me that you need a dependency injection framework, or, you need to just load all of the code up front.

Comment: I've considered doing the later. As far as the framework, are there any that you can recommend?

Comment: I assume you mean former, asin dependency injection? I've used require.js in the past, seemed to do the job pretty well. I'm not too familiar with what is available now days because I haven't had a need for it in a while. I tend to load the majority of my code up front for applications, and my sites use very little js.

Comment: I meant to say that I've considered loading all of the code up front. I'll check require.js out though.

In the context of an online web application/game, I imagine my users will expect some loading. Do you think it would be a problem to load all of my scripts up front? It amounts to at most 20 kilobytes minified.

Comment: I don't think 20kb would impact load time that much.

Comment: When you fetch somepage.html with `$.get` is it just a partial (for example a `<div>lots of content</div>` or a whole page?

Comment: It's a whole page @Matijs.

Comment: Why would you do that? You already have a page. Sounds to me you only need a partial. The page you're putting your partial into should have the JavaScript, whether that's via RequireJS or all in one go depends.

Comment: Some of the pages are just partial loads while others are not (in this case it's a whole page). For consistency I'm using History to interact with all of them. If someone wants to recommend dependency injection or all in one in an answer, I'll happily accept it. :)

Comment: I tend to avoid loading scripts in the html because then you have to deal with removing references to libraries/plugins that are already included. It begins to get very complicated at that point. For example, the demo html you included includes a link to jquery.js. that would have to be removed before you could compile the elements down dom nodes, which can only be done with string manipulation. If you parsed it with jQuery, it would execute the scripts before you could remove them, thus defeating the point of loading the pages with ajax.

Comment: Sound like RequireJS is the answer for me then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is certainly possible, but it's not going to be very maintainable in the long-run.

One of the biggest issues you'll run into is properly injecting the code from the ajax loaded html into the current page. You can't just ignore it and let it all run because then you'll be including libraries multiple times (resulting in plugins getting overwritten/removed), and the code for the page you are loading may happen too soon due to the dom already being ready.

This pretty much leaves you with two options: dependency injection or front-loading.

**Dependency injection** will probably be the easiest of the two for you to implement because it requires the least amount of changes to your current code-base. All you would have to do is ensure that all pages requested with ajax only include the content of the `<body>` (which can be done with server-side code), and ensure that all page-specific code is included before the closing `</body>` of each page. Then you would just have to use the dependency-injection methods to run your code with the proper dependencies.

You could also have it only include `<div id="#content">...</div>` for your partials, which ever makes more sense for your use-case.

**Front-loading** would be a little more difficult because you'll have this one giant file that has all of your code for all of the pages, unless you use a build process (if you've never used a build-process before, you really should try it, even if you don't think you need it.) With front-loading, you'll either have to use event delegation, or have init methods for each page that you selectively execute as you load each page. This could become a maintainability nightmare without good build processes.

Answer (score 0):

You can call functions from the original scripts on the page which you have loaded. For Instance you could do this in your main:

```
<script>
    function ExternalScriptLoaded(){}
</script>
```

Then on your external page:

```
<script>
    try{ ExternalScriptLoaded(); }catch(err){alert('This page was not loaded with ajax because i can't find the function');}
</script>
```

The alert will trigger if the script can't find the function on your main page.
i.e. call the function after you know the script has finished runnng.
Hope this helped.

Comment: If I'm calling a function that relies on an injected script file that I'm not sure has loaded, how do I know it will be called at an appropriate time?

Comment: That's what my original question is asking. Hopefully my edits will clarify.

Comment: Did you create the script file that's being injected? If so, document.ready will trigger within that, then once it has finished resolving, do the try catch. Otherwise you can use .done and call it within there?

Comment: The first I didn't create and the second I did but it depends on the first.

Comment: So technically you should know when the second script resolves then, as the first one is a prerequisite. Then you can just do the try catch when you're ready.

Comment: And you will know this because the $(document).ready function will trigger once it is instantiated onto the page.